# Is there native software similar to Comic Book Life for Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics

Is there native software similar to [Comic Book Life](http://plasq.com/products/comiclife2/) for Linux? If you've ever used the software you'll see that it's specially designed and optimised for easily creating simple comic books. I've already tried using Inkscape and GIMP (with some custom templates) and whilst they allow for finer control of graphics they're far too complex for the task at hand

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [TBO](https://github.com/danigm/TBO)

[image]

> It is a Gnome comic creator.
>
> TBO is an easy and fun program to draw comics and make your presentations funnier.

Comment: hi, the link does not work anymore? is it decommissioned?

Comment: never mind, found it: https://github.com/danigm/TBO

Answer (score 1):

**[KRITA](https://krita.org/en/)**

*Professional free and open source painting program*

If you want to get more features, such as:

- Rich User Interface
- Brush Stabilizers
- Pop-up Pallete
- Brush Engines
- Wrap around Mode
- Resource Manager

[image]